# Solve System of Differential Equations using a Table with two variables

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations, using Table to define the equations I want to solve. I managed to do it with a table with one index, as there is an example in the docs, but I couldn't do it with a matrix. I tried the following code:

```
eqns = {
  Table[
   Derivative[1][y[i, j]][t] == y[i, j][t] - y[i, j][t - 1],
   {i, 1, 3},
   {j, 1, 3}
   ],
  Table[
   y[i, j][t /; t <= 0] == Exp[t*i + j],
   {i, 1, 3},
   {j, 1, 3}
   ]
  }
NDSolve[eqns, Table[y[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}], {t, 30}];
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[i, j][t], {i, 3}, {j, 3}] /. %], {t, 0, 30}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try `NDSolve[eqns,Table[y[i,j],{i,3},{j,3}]//Flatten,{t,30}]`. The only difference is the additional `// Flatten`. Look at the output of `NDSolve` with and without `// Flatten` to see the difference.

Comment: @user293787 thank you very much! I understand the difference now. If you want to put the comment as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution.